# I can't access my website from outside Windows Server 2012 using IIS and IISNode

Tags: node.js, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, iisnode

I bought a new dedicated server. I have a MEAN Stack application (Node.js, Angular, MongoDB, Express) and wanted to take advantage of using IIS to publish my webapp.

I followed [this guide](http://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode) to install iisnode and make a litle node.js server working.

I did it and succesfully tried http://iisnode.local in my browser inside the server.

Ont he other hand, if I try http://(theIPoftheserver)/iisnode.local am I am getting the following error:

[image]

I need to do something for the server to be accesible from outside but I don't know what..

If i go to http://(theIPoftheserver)/ I can see IIS website and even if I go to http://(theIPoftheserver)/node I can see the iisnode website...

I am quite newbie and I need some help...

My web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a node.js application
        to be handled by the iisnode module -->

        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>


        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="sendToNode">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <iisnode enableXFF="true" />

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: I also have to mention that I have a new rule in windows' hosts file as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   iisnode.local
```

EDIT2: can windows firewall be blocking something? Do I need to disconnect it?

IMPORTANT EDIT 14.09.2016: if I edit hosts file and add:

```
<server-ip-address> iisnode.local
```

And then I the I visit http://iisnode.local it works!
I don't understand it very well why though.. i don't want all the users of my website to modify their hosts file, what can I do?

I don't know is this could be the source of the problem?

EDIT: My Website bindings look like this:

[image]

Comment: Firewall properly is not the issue as the error page shown in screenshot is from IIS. This seems like IIS configuration issue. Maybe in IIS, your site is bind to localhost(127.0.0.1) only.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue beacuse I can see /node from outside...

Comment: Important edition done in OP

Comment: Add your external IP to your website binding. (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734869.aspx ). If this works then I put it into an answer.

Comment: No. It is IIS website configuration binding, the link have detail instructions.

Comment: @JohnSiu thanks for your help but I can't make it work. In the website's binding i already have a binding for all IPs to iisnode.local. Please see the OP with the screenshot. If I add another rule with the external IP of the server nothing changes

Comment: Add a new binding, same as the one you currently have, but leave the hostname empty, and use external IP.

Comment: @JohnSiu done, nothing changes...

Comment: I have to say that http:\\iisnode.local only works in the server too if there is a rule in server's hosts file with 
127.0.0.1  iisnode.local

Comment: the iisnode.local will only work in the server, that is normal.

Comment: You may have to disable or delete your default site for the IP only rules to work.

Comment: OMG, I re-read your question, your site is actually working!!!

Comment: @JohnSiu yes, but only accesible from outside if I add <server-ip-address> iisnode.local rule to my personal computer's hosts file

Comment: Answer created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access your site within the server with

> http://iisnode.local (by hostname)

It is same as

> http://127.0.0.1/ (by IP)

So when you use IP address, you don't put iisnode.local after it.

iisnode.local is hostname, in an URL, you either use hostname OR IP, not the same time.

> http://(theIPoftheserver)/iisnode.local

is equal to

> http://(IP)/(hostname) <--- That is wrong!

Currently, I am assuming you don't have public dns setup for your server, the correct way to access the site will be

> http://(External-IP)/ <-- No iisnode.local after it.

Comment: thanks for your help! I just needed to create and A rule in my domains DNS config. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Egidi, what did you do? I have the exact same problem and found this post helpful. I can now access the site using <ServerIP> issnode.local by having this in my hosts file. How did you edit your DNS to fix this?