# Node.js with IIS using IISNode. I need to make a DNS rule so the site is accessible from outside the server without modifying the hosts file

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I currently have the same problem as described in this question [question!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418811/i-cant-access-my-website-from-outside-windows-server-2012-using-iis-and-iisnode/39497321)

I can access my Node.js site only if i modify my own hosts file to have (serverIP) NameOfSite, but typing that into the url doesnt work.

In the comments under the ansewer to that question it says that the person fixed this issue by adding a rule in their DNS. How would you do that? I am googling how to make rules in DNS and its not getting me anywhere and im seeing a lot of sites about firewalls.

Comment: Talk to your network administrators if you work for a company. If you attempts this at a home network, you usually set up a DNS server on your own.

Comment: I'm the guy whose suppose to handle all this stuff. I'm a new graduate software engineer and have never edited DNS, so i was hoping to find out how to do this successfully. The person in the post i linked said they just added a rule and were good to go, but i dont know what they did.

Comment: Teaching what is DNS and how to configure it clearly goes off-topic. Once you know what is DNS and how it works, then what those guys did would be crystal clear. You might get started from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System and there are tons of online course on computer networking.

Comment: I know what it is, and we have one. I was just hoping there would be a command or something to edit it. Maybe someone knew what that person did and they could post it here. It seems IISNode isn't going to work without knowing how to do this since other people are having the exact same problem as described in that post.

Comment: Nope. There is no "command" or "something" unless you really know what DNS set up you should go and what DNS settings should be used. That's exactly why nobody tries to write too many steps (as they vary case by case), and everyone wanting to follow the answer MUST study carefully the background knowledge.